# What precautions should I take when using snow chains?

Tags: tires, wheels, winter, wear, snow-chain

I have purchased some snow chains, but the manual provides fitting instructions, and it only says to remove them when the road is completely clear of snow, and never drive faster than 40mph (about 65kph).

**Are there any other precautions that I should take when using snow chains?**

Snow chains are permitted on the front wheels on my front wheel drive car. It also says they must not be used on the rear wheels.

**Why can't I use snow chains on the rear wheels?**

**Are snow chains likely to cause tyre damage if used properly?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are there any other precautions that I should take when using snow chains?

Not really ... what they give in the instructions are spot on. ***DO NOT*** exceed the 40mph or vehicle damage will ensue. You can also lose control of the vehicle if running faster than recommended. Running chains on bare roadways will cause damage to the road surface.

> Why can't I use snow chains on the rear wheels?

You only want them on the drive tires. It will drag your vehicle down having them on non-drive tires. It could actually make things worse than without them.

> Are snow chains likely to cause tyre damage if used properly?

Not if used properly, no it is not likely. What you really have to pay attention to is if any part of the chain starts flying around because it is not properly secured, you could ensue vehicle damage (wheel well, fender, drive components, brake lines, etc). Going too fast with them on the vehicle is the *easiest* way to cause this type of damage. Follow the instructions to ensure you don't have issues.